# Nextflow+Singularity: No such file or directory, even though file exists

Tags: docker, filesystems, singularity-container, nextflow

I am trying to run this [pipeline](https://github.com/sanger-pathogens/companion/), which is implemented with Nextflow and uses a Docker container. Unfortunately I cannot use Docker, since it is not HPC compatible (no sudo), so I am using Singularity instead of Docker. However, it seems that the paths are not mounted correctly, since I am getting this error:

```
Error executing process > 'truncate_input_headers'

Caused by:
  Process `truncate_input_headers` terminated with an error exit status (1)

Command executed:

  truncate_header.lua < phased.1_scaffolds_FINAL.fasta > truncated.fasta

Command exit status:
  1

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  .command.sh: line 2: phased.1_scaffolds_FINAL.fasta: No such file or directory

Work dir:
  /work/project/ladsie_002/work/77/1854982bdacdd60fbe447554ab153b

Tip: you can replicate the issue by changing to the process work dir and entering the command `bash .command.run`
```

However, when I look into the path, the file does indeed exist:

```
$ ll /work/project/ladsie_002/work/77/1854982bdacdd60fbe447554ab153b
total 1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bbrink users 76 30. Aug 13:44 phased.1_scaffolds_FINAL.fasta -> /work/project/ladsie_002/companion/input/pleo/phased.1_scaffolds_FINAL.fasta
```

This is my config:

```
env {
    GT_RETAINIDS = "yes"
    AUGUSTUS_CONFIG_PATH = "/opt/data/augustus"
    FILTER_SHORT_PARTIALS_RULE = "/opt/data/filters/filter_short_partials.lua"
    PFAM = "/opt/pfam/Pfam-A.hmm"
    PFAM2GO = "/opt/data/pfam2go/pfam2go.txt"
    RATT_CONFIG = "/opt/RATT/RATT.config_euk_NoPseudo_SpliceSite"
}

params.GO_OBO = "/opt/go.obo"
params.NCRNA_MODELS = "/opt/data/cm/rnas.cm"
params.CIRCOS_CONFIG_FILE = "/opt/data/circos/circos.debian.conf"
params.CIRCOS_BIN_CONFIG_FILE = "/opt/data/circos/circos.bin.debian.conf"
params.SPECFILE = "/opt/data/speck/output_check.lua"
params.AUGUSTUS_EXTRINSIC_CFG = "/opt/data/augustus/extrinsic.cfg"

process {
    container = 'sangerpathogens/companion:latest'
}

singularity {
    enabled = true
//    autoMounts = true
}

executor {
    name = 'local'
    queueSize = 2
    pollInterval = '3sec'
}
```

I tried to find a solution for this, the only thing I could find was the `autoMounts = true` option (commented out above), which causes the pipeline to not even find it's own lua scripts when enabled:

```
Error executing process > 'truncate_input_headers'

Caused by:
  Process `truncate_input_headers` terminated with an error exit status (127)

Command executed:

  truncate_header.lua < phased.1_scaffolds_FINAL.fasta > truncated.fasta

Command exit status:
  127

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  .command.sh: line 2: truncate_header.lua: command not found

Work dir:
  /work/project/ladsie_002/work/95/f03b31ed18a84f331b83cad0232bd5

Tip: you can try to figure out what's wrong by changing to the process work dir and showing the script file named `.command.sh`
```

Edit1:
I followed the advice of tsnowlan and added `--debug` to `singularity.engineOptions`. However, the path in question seems to be mounted:

```
Error executing process > 'truncate_input_headers'

Caused by:
  Process `truncate_input_headers` terminated with an error exit status (1)

Command executed:

  truncate_header.lua < phased.1_scaffolds_FINAL.fasta > truncated.fasta

Command exit status:
  1

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Mounting tmpfs to /var/singularity/mnt/session
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountImage()                  Mounting loop device /dev/loop0 to /var/singularity/mnt/session/rootfs
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Mounting overlay to /var/singularity/mnt/session/final
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   setPropagationMount()         Set RPC mount propagation flag to SLAVE
  VERBOSE [U=1038,P=29509]   Passwd()                      Checking for template passwd file: /var/singularity/mnt/session/rootfs/etc/passwd
  VERBOSE [U=1038,P=29509]   Passwd()                      Creating passwd content
  VERBOSE [U=1038,P=29509]   Passwd()                      Creating template passwd file and appending user data: /var/singularity/mnt/session/rootfs/etc/passwd
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   addIdentityMount()            Adding /etc/passwd to mount list
  VERBOSE [U=1038,P=29509]   addIdentityMount()            Default mount: /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd
  VERBOSE [U=1038,P=29509]   Group()                       Checking for template group file: /var/singularity/mnt/session/rootfs/etc/group
  VERBOSE [U=1038,P=29509]   Group()                       Creating group content
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   addIdentityMount()            Adding /etc/group to mount list
  VERBOSE [U=1038,P=29509]   addIdentityMount()            Default mount: /etc/group:/etc/group
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Remounting /var/singularity/mnt/session/final
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Mounting /dev to /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/dev
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Mounting /etc/localtime to /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Mounting /etc/hosts to /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/etc/hosts
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Mounting /etc/singularity/actions to /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/.singularity.d/actions
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Remounting /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/.singularity.d/actions
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Mounting /proc to /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/proc
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Remounting /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/proc
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Mounting sysfs to /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/sys
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Mounting /home/bbrink to /var/singularity/mnt/session/home/bbrink
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Remounting /var/singularity/mnt/session/home/bbrink
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Mounting /var/singularity/mnt/session/home/bbrink to /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/home/bbrink
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Remounting /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/home/bbrink
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Mounting /tmp to /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/tmp
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Remounting /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/tmp
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Mounting /var/tmp to /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/var/tmp
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Remounting /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/var/tmp
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Mounting /work/project/ladsie_002/work/de/74a8bbd8bd11ad1524800fb7e71556 to /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/work/project/ladsie_002/work/de/74a8bbd8bd11ad1524800fb7e71556
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Remounting /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/work/project/ladsie_002/work/de/74a8bbd8bd11ad1524800fb7e71556
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Mounting /var/singularity/mnt/session/etc/resolv.conf to /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/etc/resolv.conf
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Mounting /var/singularity/mnt/session/etc/passwd to /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/etc/passwd
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   mountGeneric()                Mounting /var/singularity/mnt/session/etc/group to /var/singularity/mnt/session/final/etc/group
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   create()                      Chroot into /var/singularity/mnt/session/final
  DEBUG   [U=0,P=29543]      Chroot()                      Change current directory to /var/singularity/mnt/session/final
  DEBUG   [U=0,P=29543]      Chroot()                      Hold reference to host / directory
  DEBUG   [U=0,P=29543]      Chroot()                      Called pivot_root on /var/singularity/mnt/session/final
  DEBUG   [U=0,P=29543]      Chroot()                      Change current directory to host / directory
  DEBUG   [U=0,P=29543]      Chroot()                      Apply slave mount propagation for host / directory
  DEBUG   [U=0,P=29543]      Chroot()                      Called unmount(/, syscall.MNT_DETACH)
  DEBUG   [U=0,P=29543]      Chroot()                      Changing directory to / to avoid getpwd issues
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   create()                      Chdir into / to avoid errors
  VERBOSE [U=1038,P=29542]   startup()                     Execute stage 2
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29542]   Stage()                       Entering stage 2
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   PostStartProcess()            Post start process
  .command.sh: line 2: phased.1_scaffolds_FINAL.fasta: No such file or directory
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   CleanupContainer()            Cleanup container
  DEBUG   [U=1038,P=29509]   Master()                      Child exited with exit status 1

Work dir:
  /work/project/ladsie_002/work/de/74a8bbd8bd11ad1524800fb7e71556
```

Edit2:
I fixed the faulty mount point, which lead to another error:

```
gt: error: could not execute script ...rk/project/ladsie_002/companion/bin/gff3_to_embl.lua:74: bad argument #1 to 'lines' (/opt/go.obo: Permission denied)
```

I guess the permissions inside the container are not set correctly.

Comment: What version of singularity are you using to build the image and what version to run it? Are you running nextflow directly on a VM or using slurm/PBS to submit to a cluster?

Comment: singularity version 3.2.1-1.1.el7.
Right now I am testing to run nextflow directly on the head/master node of the cluster. Once I solve this issue, I will modify the config to use SLURM in order to submit jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pditommaso mentioned, you need to ensure the environment inside the singularity image is setup properly. You can do this either via the `%environment` block in Singularity definition file or exporting `SINGULARITY_$VARNAME` in the host environment. e.g., `SINGULARITY_PERL5LIB=/opt/ORTHOMCLV1.4/:/opt/RATT/:/opt/ABACAS2/:$PERL5LIB` in the `env` block of the nextflow config to set the `PERL5LIB` variable inside the container.

It's also likely that you'll need to specify the location of the data to mount into the container in `singularity.runOptions`. The specifics there depend on which version of Singularity you're using and if the host OS has OverlayFS enabled in its kernel.

*Edit 1: binding/mounting*

The basic form is `-B /host/path:/image/path`. If `/image/path` does not exist in the singularity image, and OverlayFS is not enabled in the OS kernel, you will get an error message: `WARNING: Skipping user bind, non existent bind point (directory/file) in container: '/image/path'`. Where `directory/file` is what's being mounted.

You can view what is being mounted in by using `--debug` flag with version 3+, or `-vv` in version 2. In nextflow, this gets added to `singularity.engineOptions`.

Be aware that any symlinks in the mounted directory will be broken if they reference a path that is not available in the singularity image.

If data mounted includes symlinks, there is often a good chance they refer to files that are not mounted into the container and appear to be broken links when the singularity image is run.

*edit 2: file permissions*

The simplest way to build the singularity image is `sudo singularity build companion.sif docker://sangerpathogens/companion:latest`. If you need to modify anything, as in the case of the `/opt/go.obo` file, you'll need to create a definition file.

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: sangerpathogens/companion:latest
# note: for reproducibility, it is best to use a tag whose target won't change over time

%post
    chmod 644 /opt/go.obo
```

If there are any other changes needed, they go in the `%post` block. Unlike Docker, singularity doesn't use layers per command to create the image, so you don't have to worry about chaining `some_command && some_other_command && so_on && etc`.

Comment: I am running singularity version 3.2.1-1.1.el7. How do I find out if the host OS has OverlayFS enabled and how do I correctly mount the data? The PATH seems to be set alright, it's the data that has been linked by nextflow which cannot be seen.

Comment: Add `--debug` to `singularity.runOptions`. In the nextflow logs, grep for `Mounting /`. That will show you all the host locations being mounted inside the container. 

If OverlayFS is not enabled and the directory you're attempting to mount your data to does not exist, you will see a warning in the process log "Skipping use bind, non existent bind point ...".

Comment: updated answer with additional binding/mounting instructions. OverlayFS is probably okay. Mostly an issue if your cluster is running older operating systems (cento/rhel 6, ubuntu 14.04, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, one has to add `--debug` to `singularity.engineOptions`. However, the path seems to be mounted. I updated the question.

Comment: Looks like the error message changed a little. `.command.sh: line 2: phased.1_scaffolds_FINAL.fasta: No such file or directory`. Might want to check the path to the data files / your working directory is where you think it is and adjust the command.

Comment: The error message is the same as posted above in my original question and the file is indeed existing in the same folder as .command.sh. Unfortunately I am still lost here.

Comment: I think I missed this at the beginning. Is the file in the `work` directory a symlink to a different file? If so, there's a good chance the file being linked to isn't in the image and the program is just seeing a broken link. Try running on the linked file directly or adding `-B /work` to `singularity.runOptions`.

Comment: Thanks, it finally worked! However, I get a new error due to missing permissions for `/opt` inside the container (I think).

Comment: Looks like that file has `rw` permission for root only. You can `chmod 666 /opt/go.obo` in the `%post` block of the singularity definition file. I'll update above answer with a stub. There may be more files with that issue if the docker container was not expecting to be run by a non-root user.

Comment: Actually, while `chmod 666` would work, the singularity image is read only, so `chmod 644` (or `chmod o+r`) is fine.

Comment: I was fearing that I will have to build my own container. I can't do that on the machine since I don't have sudo permission. I tried remote build, but it gave me an out of memory exception. Seems like this project is cursed lol. Thanks for your time, you solved my original questions and I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Singulary may be failing properly convert the user environment defined Docker container. Make sure the Singularity image define `PATH` and other variables as defined in the project Dockerfile https://github.com/sanger-pathogens/companion/blob/master/Dockerfile#L107

Comment: The PATH is set correct (in the first case at least) since it finding the tools and scripts inside the Docker container. What is does not find is the files outside the container on my file system.

Answer (score 1):

This fix will help with the truncate_headers.lua script not being present.

https://github.com/sanger-pathogens/companion/issues/93